# how to change django admin action style

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have some action in my django application admin page and I need one button for  each action insted of selecting each action and click on go button how can I do It?
I know I should change actions.html for adding button, but I dont' know how to handle this button on django.contrib.admin.options.py :

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    """
    The 'change list' admin view for this model.
    """
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ERROR_FLAG
    opts = self.model._meta
    app_label = opts.app_label
    if not self.has_change_permission(request, None):
        raise PermissionDenied

    list_display = self.get_list_display(request)
    list_display_links = self.get_list_display_links(request, list_display)
    list_filter = self.get_list_filter(request)

    # Check actions to see if any are available on this changelist
    actions = self.get_actions(request)
    if actions:
        # Add the action checkboxes if there are any actions available.
        list_display = ['action_checkbox'] +  list(list_display)

    ChangeList = self.get_changelist(request)
    try:
        cl = ChangeList(request, self.model, list_display,
            list_display_links, list_filter, self.date_hierarchy,
            self.search_fields, self.list_select_related,
            self.list_per_page, self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable,
            self)
    except IncorrectLookupParameters:
        # Wacky lookup parameters were given, so redirect to the main
        # changelist page, without parameters, and pass an 'invalid=1'
        # parameter via the query string. If wacky parameters were given
        # and the 'invalid=1' parameter was already in the query string,
        # something is screwed up with the database, so display an error
        # page.
        if ERROR_FLAG in request.GET.keys():
            return SimpleTemplateResponse('admin/invalid_setup.html', {
                'title': _('Database error'),
            })
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path + '?' + ERROR_FLAG + '=1')

    # If the request was POSTed, this might be a bulk action or a bulk
    # edit. Try to look up an action or confirmation first, but if this
    # isn't an action the POST will fall through to the bulk edit check,
    # below.
    action_failed = False
    selected = request.POST.getlist(helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)

    # Actions with no confirmation
    if (actions and request.method == 'POST' and
            'index' in request.POST and '_save' not in request.POST):
        if selected:
            response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_query_set(request))
            if response:
                return response
            else:
                action_failed = True
        else:
            msg = _("Items must be selected in order to perform "
                    "actions on them. No items have been changed.")
            self.message_user(request, msg)
            action_failed = True

    # Actions with confirmation
    if (actions and request.method == 'POST' and
            helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME in request.POST and
            'index' not in request.POST and '_save' not in request.POST):
        if selected:
            response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_query_set(request))
            if response:
                return response
            else:
                action_failed = True

    # If we're allowing changelist editing, we need to construct a formset
    # for the changelist given all the fields to be edited. Then we'll
    # use the formset to validate/process POSTed data.
    formset = cl.formset = None

    # Handle POSTed bulk-edit data.
    if (request.method == "POST" and cl.list_editable and
            '_save' in request.POST and not action_failed):
        FormSet = self.get_changelist_formset(request)
        formset = cl.formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=cl.result_list)
        if formset.is_valid():
            changecount = 0
            for form in formset.forms:
                if form.has_changed():
                    obj = self.save_form(request, form, change=True)
                    self.save_model(request, obj, form, change=True)
                    self.save_related(request, form, formsets=[], change=True)
                    change_msg = self.construct_change_message(request, form, None)
                    self.log_change(request, obj, change_msg)
                    changecount += 1

            if changecount:
                if changecount == 1:
                    name = force_text(opts.verbose_name)
                else:
                    name = force_text(opts.verbose_name_plural)
                msg = ungettext("%(count)s %(name)s was changed successfully.",
                                "%(count)s %(name)s were changed successfully.",
                                changecount) % {'count': changecount,
                                                'name': name,
                                                'obj': force_text(obj)}
                self.message_user(request, msg)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

    # Handle GET -- construct a formset for display.
    elif cl.list_editable:
        FormSet = self.get_changelist_formset(request)
        formset = cl.formset = FormSet(queryset=cl.result_list)

    # Build the list of media to be used by the formset.
    if formset:
        media = self.media + formset.media
    else:
        media = self.media

    # Build the action form and populate it with available actions.
    if actions:
        action_form = self.action_form(auto_id=None)
        action_form.fields['action'].choices = self.get_action_choices(request)
    else:
        action_form = None

    selection_note_all = ungettext('%(total_count)s selected',
        'All %(total_count)s selected', cl.result_count)

    context = {
        'module_name': force_text(opts.verbose_name_plural),
        'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
        'selection_note_all': selection_note_all % {'total_count': cl.result_count},
        'title': cl.title,
        'is_popup': cl.is_popup,
        'cl': cl,
        'media': media,
        'has_add_permission': self.has_add_permission(request),
        'app_label': app_label,
        'action_form': action_form,
        'actions_on_top': self.actions_on_top,
        'actions_on_bottom': self.actions_on_bottom,
        'actions_selection_counter': self.actions_selection_counter,
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})

    return TemplateResponse(request, self.change_list_template or [
        'admin/%s/%s/change_list.html' % (app_label, opts.object_name.lower()),
        'admin/%s/change_list.html' % app_label,
        'admin/change_list.html'
    ], context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . It was add a button to actions.html:

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="delete" value="delete">Delete</button>
```

and in options.py:

```
def response_action(self, request, queryset):
    .....
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data['action']= 'delete_selected'
    data.pop(helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME, None)
    data.pop("index", None)
    .....
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    ....
    if ('delete' in request.POST and request.method == 'POST'  and '_save' not in request.POST):
        if selected:
            response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_query_set(request))
            if response:
                return response
            else:
                action_failed = True
        else:
            msg = _("Items must be selected in order to perform "
                    "actions on them. No items have been changed.")
            self.message_user(request, msg)
            action_failed = True   
    ....
```